# How to disable downlaod button after 10 clicks Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a custom WordPress theme, and i am little stuck in one situation, the client wants that when the user buy subscription on his WordPress site, then the user can download documents, (the users are downloading documents its done). Now the problem is that, the download should be limited as per plan choice, for example:- if a user buys $100 subscription pack then..user can click on  download button.. for only 50 times. and if he buys $200 subscription pack then..user can click on  download button.. for only 100 times. (*note:- the download button is available on every post so , every time when user click on any post  download Resume button, the count should be -1. until he reaches to 0 and disabled download button )
I don't have any clue how to do this, is there any specific key idea behind this or any WordPress plugin to do this thing.

Here below is the image to get an idea of the concept ;
[view Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7K0r.png)

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? Do you want to get two separate sets of results, or get the combined results, or get a set of results that match criteria for Featured and Rating? Can you give us an example because it not clear what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: You can not run two different queries with just one _call_ to `wp_query`. You are only modifying query arguments with what you have shown above (and `wp_reset_query` in there makes zero sense), that does not make it execute two queries instead of one all of a sudden.